# result of my js calculation is not stored in mysql

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Good day,

I experimented with a simple JS math calculation.
this calculation works as expected, but additionally I wanted to store the math calculation in a database where all values (the input fields and the result .textContent) should be stored. Afterwards the calculation should be named and populated by a dropdown menu, but that's a different story.

So, I added some nice ajax code, see this: https://phppot.com/php/php-mysql-inline-editing-using-jquery-ajax/

Everything works as expected, the only issue I have is that I don't get the result of the math automatically updated into the database, so if I change the math input fields or refresh the site, the result is lost.

I put up an live example with mysql backened to show you exactly what I mean:

http://90.153.105.10:8888/djdp42Bjjr39399nfjjj39xleit832991vnJ39921/live/test.php

dbcontroller.php:

```html
<?php
class DBController {
    private $host = "ip";
    private $user = "root";
    private $password = "thepassword";
    private $database = "the database";
    private $conn;
    
    function __construct() {
        $this->conn = $this->connectDB();
    }
    
    function connectDB() {
        $conn = mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password,$this->database);
        return $conn;
    }
    
    function runQuery($query) {
        $result = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $resultset[] = $row;
        }       
        if(!empty($resultset))
            return $resultset;
    }
    
    function numRows($query) {
        $result = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
        $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        return $rowcount;   
    }
    function executeUpdate($query) {
        $result = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);        
        return $result;     
    }
}
?>
```

saveedit.php

```html
<?php
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
$result = $db_handle->executeUpdate("UPDATE database_table set " . $_POST["column"] . " = '".$_POST["editval"]."' WHERE  id=".$_POST["id"]);;
?>
```

test.php

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script>

        function showEdit(editableObj) {
            $(editableObj);
        } 
        
        function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id) {
            $(editableObj);
            $.ajax({
                url: "saveedit.php",
                type: "POST",
                data:'column='+column+'&editval='+editableObj.innerHTML+'&id='+id,
                success: function(data){
                    $(editableObj);
                }        
           });
        }
        
        </script>
        
   </head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style>}
</style>
<body>

<table class="tbl-qa">

<tr>
    <td >DESCRIPTION:</td>
                      
        <td contenteditable="true" id="Event" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'event','0')" onClick="showEdit(this);">This is a simple stored description for the following math. As you can see, the result and math values are editiable. But the RESULT is not beeing stored nor will it get calculated when refreshing the site :/<br></td>
            
                 
        </table>
<hr>
<table class="tbl-qa">
      <tr>
    <td>VALUE 1:</td>
                      
        <td contenteditable="true" id="Tank" size="2" oninput="output();output2();output3();" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'Tank','0')" onClick="showEdit(this);">10</td>
            
         
    <td>VALUE 2:</td>
                      
        <td contenteditable="true" id="Spritverbrauch" size="2" oninput="output();output3();" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'Spritverbrauch','0')" onClick="showEdit(this);">2</td>
            
         
   </tr>
   <tr>
  <p></p>
<td>RESULT: </td>
                                  
        <td contenteditable="true" size="2" id="StintlangeRd" oninput="output();output3();" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'StintlangeRd','0')" onClick="showEdit(this);"></td>
            
         
    </tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">

function output(){

    var value2 = document.getElementById('Tank').textContent;
    var value3 = document.getElementById('Spritverbrauch').textContent;
    document.getElementById('StintlangeRd').innerHTML = (parseFloat(value2) / parseFloat(value3)).toFixed(2);

}

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   setTimeout(function(){
       location.reload();
   },60000);
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Self-vandalism rolled back. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209436/self-vandalism-what-is-correct-action

Answer (score 0):

After updating try to run a query with 'COMMIT' to confirm the update on mysql database!

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the values arrive at your update script. I think the problem may lie within your AJAX call:

```
function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id) {
            $(editableObj);
            $.ajax({
                url: "saveedit.php",
                type: "POST",
                data:'column='+column+'&editval='+editableObj.innerHTML+'&id='+id,
                success: function(data){
                    $(editableObj);
                }        
           });
        }
```

Inside this function, you set the data by passing a query string. Instead of a query string, you should use a plain old javascript object.

```
data: {
    column : column,
    editval : editableObj.innerHTML,
    id : id
},
```

Comment: thanks. I tried that but unfortunately no luck. How should the complete function look like? Sorry, I am new to this ;)

Comment: I have no experience with mysqli_query etc, but what I would recommend is to var_dump($_POST) inside your save script and check the response through chrome devtools network tab. If the correct data is available, the query or database will be at fault.

Comment: If at all possible, I'd recommend switching to PDO instead of mysqli. It's much safer, easier, and protects against sql injection if you use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Change Ajax Post Data you are sending data in **GET** method and trying to get data by **POST** Method

```js
function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "saveedit.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      column : column,
      editval : editableObj.innerHTML, // just check it or use $(editableObj).html() if necessary
      id : id
    },
    success: function(data){
      // you will get your response here which is sent from server
    }        
   });
}
```

Comment: thanks, how should the whole function look like? Just both get/post function behind each other?

Comment: alright, updated the code. Unfortunately not working as it should :/ Any other idea?

Comment: can you please me your problem or error you are facing, so that i can help you ?